# Embedded Spring Cloud Config - How to retrieve a plain file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

I configured a very simple Spring Boot application with the following Gradle dependency:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

The idea is to **embed** the Spring Cloud Config Server into the application.

The content of the `bootstrap.yml` file is the following:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        git:
          username: git
          password: <personal-access-token>
          uri: <github-uri>
```

The remote GitHub repo contains this `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  port: 8280
```

When I start the Spring Boot application it correctly retrieves the remote configuration, because the log contains the following:

```
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8280 (http)
...
Tomcat started on port(s): 8280 (http) with context path ''
```

My question is: if I put in the remote GitHub repo a file named `dummy.txt` at the same level of `application.yml`, what is the programmatic way to retrieve its content from the application itself?
I know that with separated Config Client and Config Server, from the Config Client I can rely on [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html) in order to retrieve a plain text file from the Config Server. How to achieve the same result when the Config Server is embedded in the application?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I got so far is based on `org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceRepository`

In a class annotate as `@Service`/`@Component`, .. just include the following:

```
@Autowired private ResourceRepository resourceRepo;
```

Next, assuming that the default profile is named `default` and that the configuration is stored in the branch named `main`, the following line of code is able to retrieve the file content:

```
resourceRepo.findOne(null, "default", "main", "dummy.txt").getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Note: for the `@Autowired` to work, the `@EnableConfigServer` annotation is required. This means that the application embedding the config server can leak configuration information if contacted via HTTP at a generic `/foo/bar` path as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_actuator_and_security). To mitigate the problem it is important to configure `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix` with an explicit value and then protect the endpoint `<prefix>/*`